# Grails Spring Security plugin url

Tags: grails, spring-security, logout

The Grails Spring Security plugin docs shows these two properties related to logout urls (copied from https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/docs/guide/13%20URL%20Properties.gdoc)

```
logout.afterLogoutUrl | '/' | URL for redirect after logout.

logout.filterProcessesUrl | '/j_spring_security_logout' | Logout URL, intercepted by Spring Security filter.
```

When I run the s2-quickstart script to generate the `LogoutController`, the default behavior is to redirect to `logout.filterProcessesUrl`.

What is the purpose of `logout.afterLogoutUrl` if the `LogoutController` does not redirect to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Security introduces some filters, [Java filters](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html), not Grails. This filters do all authentication job, see http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html

`logout.filterProcessesUrl` handled by Spring Security filter, and after cleanup (removes user from current context, etc) it redirects to `logout.afterLogoutUrl`.

`LogoutController` does nothing, just redirects to filter. You can redirect user to this user in your own controller, or even put `<a` link to such url

Comment: So I would need to create a controller that is pointed to by `/j_spring_security_logout` that does the cleanup and then at the end of that controller, I should redirect to `logout.afterUrl`? Or does this automatically happen (I didn't see anything in `UrlMappings.groovy` that would cause this to automatically happen)?

Comment: It's automatically happen, there is a standard java filter (not Grails filter), that process `logout.filterProcessesUrl` url

Comment: Ok, thanks. 2 additional question if you don't mind. 1. Would there ever be a reason to customize the /j_spring_security_logout? I figured there must be a reason it is a customizable value. 2. Does the plugin make any compile time changes to my configuration files? I was trying to figure out where the filters were added, but I'm not sure where.

Comment: 1) Yes, you can changes `/j_spring_security_logout` to anything you want. 2) Filters are added at https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy

Comment: thanks, I guess I should be asking **why** you would want to customize j_spring_security_logout or logout.filterProcessUrl.

Comment: That is a matter of taste, it think :) For example i'm changing it to `/auth/logout`, just because all my authetnications urls are starting  with `/auth`

Comment: I'd be curious to know how you changed the URL. If I try changing it, my logout no longer works. Did you write a custom /auth/logout page? Or were you still able to leverage the existing j_spring_security_logout?

Comment: Just change `logout.filterProcessesUrl` to `/auth/logout`. What's happening when you open `/auth/logout`, does it redirect to `/`, or 404?

Comment: You're correct. I must've done something wrong when I tried before. Thanks.